# x86-64 Assembly: Understanding quadword opcode `shlq`

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I want to confirm my understanding of this specific opcode.

This line is from an assembly code from x-86-64 machine (MBP 15" 2017)
and I was confused by this instruction.

```
shlq    $5, %rsi
```

So what I know is that:

1. `shl` is a [arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3773/instructionset-27/index.html) logical shift
2. `q` here is the suffix that stands for quadword, which is 8-byte or 64-bit in x86-64 machine.

But I wasn't sure **how many total of bits it will shift**.

So I did an extensive research and I found something [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19641-01/802-1948/802-1948.pdf) that looked most relevant. On page 47, it says:

> `sal` (or its synonym `shl`) left shifts (multiplies) a byte, word, or
>   long value for a count specified by an immediate value and stores the
>   product in that byte, word, or long respectively.The second variation left > shifts by a count value specified in the CL register. The high-order bit
>   is shifted into the carry flag; the low-order bit is set to 0.

I'm not sure what they exactly mean here, especially "stores the product in that byte, word, or long" part, but Here is how I understood:

`shlq   $5, %rsi`

This will shift left 5 times. So that will make the value to be 2^5 = 32 times of it's original value. Then, it will do a product of that value with the corresponding word size which in this case is quadword, hence 8 bytes or 64-bits. In other words, it will be shifting **32*64 = 2048 bits or 32* 8-byte = 256 bytes total.**

**Am I correct?**

The same above page had an example below it but I couldn't understand it.

> Example
>
> Left shift, count specified by the constant (253), the 32-bit contents
>   of the effective address (addressed by the EDI register plus an offset
>   of 4): `shll $253, 4(%edi)`

Your help will be appreciated!

Documentations researched:

> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19641-01/802-1948/802-1948.pdf
>   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3773/instructionset-27/index.html
>   https://www.engr.mun.ca/~anderson/teaching/8894/reference/x86-assembly/
>   https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15213-s07/misc/asm64-handout.pdf
>   https://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs033/docs/guides/x64_cheatsheet.pdf
>   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5477/817-5477.pdf
>   ...and many more

Comment: The actual value in `rsi` is shifted by 5 bits left. And that is in unsigned math equal to the `rsi = rsi * 32`, so that 2^5 is used only as explanation how you can think about left shift, but the `shl` itself will just move the bits. Also I believe the CF is set to the bit which would land into non existing b64 (i.e. b59 originally, not original top bit b63). And that documentation doesn't mention quadword, only long, so it is not up to date with 64 bit, but `rsi` is 64 bit register, so 64 bit value is shifted + processed.

Comment: Keep in mind the `rsi` is physically in chip 64 bits, i.e. 64 cells with encoded value 0 or 1, so "shifting them" is sort of trivial copy from one bit to another, one by one, by the correct distance between them specified as the other argument for the `shl`. The CPU doesn't bother with multiplication, product or powers of two, it just moves those bits and clears the bottom ones.

Comment: SHL is Logical shift left and SAL is arithmetic shift left. However both these instructions do the exact same thing (unlike SHR and SAR)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks. But I'm really curious how you found the distinction. I looked at the documentation but it only says they are synonyms. Or did I miss something? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3773/6jct9o0al/index.html

Comment: You may wish to review the generated information at Felix Cloutier's site: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ . The documentation there is extracted from the Intel manuals directly.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks! I wonder why some documentations leave out such details...

Comment: Don't use the oracle docs. Use the Intel ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct until the “Then, it will do a product of that value with the corresponding word size which in this case is quadword” part.  That part doesn't happen.  The value is just multiplied by 32, that's all there is to it.

Comment: Oh no.. this actually leaves me even more confused. I'll update the question now and then let you know.

Comment: @Leonard: Intel's manuals document *exactly* what every instruction does: 
 http://felixcloutier.com/x86/SAL:SAR:SHL:SHR.html.  Note how the shift count is masked, so it wraps around if it's greater than 31 (or greater than 63 for 64-bit shifts).

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you. Could you please point out where in the document? I did run into this documentation but I do not understand this documentation, hence I can't recognize which part is relevant.

Comment: @Leonard: the "operation" section is detailed pseudo-code that tells you exactly what happens to the bits.  The "description" section is also worth reading to help understand it in English.  Most of the complexity in the docs is describing what happens to the flags; the integer result is exactly what you'd get in C from `x << 5` where `x` is a `uint64_t`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah I meant I don't understand as in I lack technical knowledge not so much of English. But thanks!

Comment: If you are confused, it is best to toss out the Intel docs and read the much more understandable AMD docs instead: https://support.amd.com/TechDocs/24594.pdf page 301.